# Java Storing Multiple Input Values to Single Array Element

Tags: java, arrays

*I want to pass all the input values to one element in an array.* I have tried to play around with arrays, but don't quite understand how they work with multiple input values.

I have read on Oracle and here but nothing really stands out or they resort to array lists.

Is there a way to encapsulate the values, then store them to an array?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mobile
{
 private String name;  
 private int number;
 private int quantity;
 private double cost;

 public Mobile(String name, int number, int quantity, double cost)
 {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.cost = cost;
 }
 public String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name)
 {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public int getNumber()
 {
  return number;
 }
 public void setNumber(int number)
 {
  this.number = number;
 }
 public int getQuantity()
 {
  return quantity;
 }
 public void setQuantity(int quantity)
 {
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }
 public double getCost()
 {
  return cost;
 }
 public void setCost(double cost)
 {
  this.cost = cost;
 }
 public double getValue()
 {
  return cost*quantity;
 }
}

public class MobilePhone
{
 public static void main (String args[])
 {
  String itemName;
  int itemNum;
  int itemQuan;
  double unitCost;

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter Item Name: ");
   itemName = input.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter Item Number: ");
   itemNum = input.nextInt();         

   System.out.print("Enter Quantity of Item: ");
   itemQuan = input.nextInt();

   System.out.print("Enter Price of Single Unit: ");
   unitCost = input.nextDouble();

   Mobile m = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do

Comment: I want to store the input values for itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost into a single element with-in an array.

Comment: So ? isn't a `Mobile[]` enough for this ?

Comment: I guess, I do not follow.

Comment: So u want new Mobile(arrayOfAllInputs)? you could create a wrapper class and store the values in there. I don't seem to get why u want to do that thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you wantot put mobile into an array of length 5, one for each mobile that is entered.
so you would declare an array `Mobile mobileValues[] = new Mobile[5];` and put each value into the array once you have collected the data `mobileValues[i] = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);`

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
  String itemName;
  int itemNum;
  int itemQuan;
  double unitCost;
  Mobile mobileValues[] = new Mobile[5];

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter Item Name: ");
      itemName = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter Item Number: ");
      itemNum = input.nextInt();         
      System.out.print("Enter Quantity of Item: ");
      itemQuan = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter Price of Single Unit: ");
      unitCost = input.nextDouble();

      mobileValues[i] = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you have
`Mobile m = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);`
is where you'd instead want to add it to your array or arrayList.

since you know you will be going through values 5 times you could add a `Mobile[] mobileArray = new Mobile[5];` at the top of your `main` with your other stuff.

then set `mobileArray[i] = new Mobile(...);`

Answer (score 1):

Since in your code you are doing a loop from 0-4, you know that you have a static size of 5 elements in your array. With that being the case, you can declare (near your other variables) an array for the objects using:

```
Mobile mobileValues[] = new Mobile[5];
```

Then, when you create a new mobile object, instead of assigning it to a variable, assign it to the index that corresponds to what number loop you are on (which is kept track of by `i` in your code.

```
mobileValues[i] = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your object declaration (which is not necessary by any means), you can do the following:

```
Mobile m = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost);
mobileValues[i] = m;
```

Since you know the amount of elements that could be added, it is not necessary, but in a more practical real world situation you would not know the amount of elements you need, and an `ArrayList` would be more suiting for this. `ArrayList`s can be defined (again, up by your other variables) using:

```
List<Mobile> mobileList = new ArrayList<Mobile>();
```

And then below, when you create the object, you can add it directly to a `list` using:

```
mobileList.add(mobileValues[i] = new Mobile(itemName, itemNum, itemQuan, unitCost));
```

This works nicely because `list`s do not require you to specify an explicit size when creating them like `array`s do. They instead adjust their size depending on the amount of elements that you add to them. You can then loop through them similar to `array`s with a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mobileList.size(); i++){
    // do stuff here
}
```

or using an iterator loop:

```
for(Mobile m : mobileList){
    // do stuff here
}
```

Again, it is not necessary to use a `list` in your solution since you know the correct size, but it is more common the need rather than an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question, and I do not seem to see any arrays or lists in your code. 
In any case, one thing you might do is to create an object which contains all the inputs that you want to put into the array element. Then you put the object in the array element. 
Something like:

```
class Token {
   Input i1;
   Input i2;
   ...
   public Token (Input a, Input b){
       i1=a; i2=b;
   }
   // Getters
}
```

Then you create an array of Token such as:

```
Token[] t = new Token[10]

t[0]= new Token(a,b);
```